# Storing spawn information for 2d platformer/scroller

Tags: game-engine

I'm looking for some idea's how best to store spawn information for a side scroller. The game I'm writing is very similar to Super Mario Bros. What I'm trying to implement is as you move through a level, enemies should spawn at particular locations. I want to store this information in the level and I don't want to just randomly spawn enemies. I'm looking for a high level strategy to store and retrieve the spawned objects when the player reaches a particular location (like mario). I couldn't find any decent tutorials or suggestions from Googleing around.

The Level is tile based so the map is Tile[][].  Each tile right now is 16x16 pixels.

The only good suggestion I've seen so far is to store the the spawning information in a 2d array where the first dimension is x and the second is y, given in tile space.  The issue I have with that implementation is that if my player is at say (160, 0) I want to spawn a particular enemy.  If however next time the level is reset the player is at (160, 5) I want to spawn the same enemy.  So for that implementation to work I have to do a scan for a given y position.

I'm looking for a more efficient storage mechanize.  I need something where I can retrieve the correct spawns quickly and not waist too much memory storing spawning locations.

Are there any common strategies in games for this?

Comment: The spawns are solely dependent on the player's `x`-coordinate?

Comment: No, some levels will allow the player to go up/down one or two screens and in that case the y position will be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there are not too many spawn-points, a simple list will do. Each list entry has the XY coordinates and spawn info. Just iterate through the list to determine whether player is near a spawn point. This is much more memory efficient than a sparsly filled 2D array, very easy to implement, and probably fast enough.

If it turns out to be not fast enough you need some kind of [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index), kd-trees are rather simple to implement and offer good performance for proximity search.
Another solution is to use a locality sensitive hash, as explained in [this paper (PDF)](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~jmesit/publications/scsc%202005.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and providing links to other implementations.  What do you think about going with a map (x, spawn) and then a list.  Most levels will be much wider than taller.

Most levels will prob. have between 15-50 spawns, so no not much, but I'm trying to avoid scanning the list each game update cycle.

Comment: Depends on how you want to determine when to spawn an enemy. If you go with something like: If the player is N tiles away, then a map doesn't help a lot, as you had to have N or in case of two-dimensional proximity N^2 map lookups. So if N or N^2 is larger than the number of spawn points it is more expensive.
Better: Presort spawn points into buckets. Say an array of 10, where first elem holds list to spawn points in the first 10th of the map (x-wise) next for the second 10th and so on. So you need to only check the player's segment and the two adjacent ones. Array lookup is cheaper than map.

Comment: So what you're saying is to create an array 1/10th of the map width (in your example).  So array[10] where the array holds a list of spawns within that x/10th of the map?

Comment: For example: Your level is 200 tiles wide. Then you have a an array  MyListType spawnPoints[10]; where spawnPoints[0] has all the spawn points with an X in between 0 and 19, spawnPoints[1] all spawn points with X in [20;39] and so on. If your player's X is at tile 42, then you only need to check lists in (42 * 10) / 200 == 2 (integer arithmetic) so spawnPoints[2] has spawn points in player's segment, spawnPoints[1] left from the player, spawnPoints[3] right from the player. Less items to check and index calculation is very cheap. Number 10 is just an example.